# Having trouble with the Rectangle Class Contains Method

Tags: java, rectangles

For some reason this is always returning False, but if you plot these points out on a graph, Rectangle 2 is clearly contained within Rectangle 1. Does anyone happen to know why this might be happening?

```java
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class RectangleDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle(4, 7, 5, 4);
        Rectangle rec2 = new Rectangle(5, 6, 2, 1);

        System.out.println(rec1.contains(rec2));
    }
}
```

Comment: `rec2` exceeds `rec1` on the upper side - `rec1` ends at `y=7` and `rec2` ends at `y=6`.

Answer (score 0):

The rectangle `rec1` would contain `rec2` if axis 0Y were directed "upwards", but in AWT this axis is directed downwards, that's why `rec2` is "on top" of `rec1`.

[image]

Comment: Wow I had no idea thats how that worked. Thank you very much for the explanation